# How can I read mysql console output using Java Process

Tags: java, mysql, windows, console

I am currently writing a Windows shell emulator using Java. Most programs seem to work fine when I use the Process.getOutputStream() method to read and display the program's output. When I run the MySql console from my program, this doesn't seem to apply though. MySql doesn't seem to print to the default system console.

How can I hook in to the MySql console to display its output and allow input to be provided by a user through my emulator?

Answer (score 0):

I think there is two problems to manage. The first is rescue the output and you can use this article (http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.htm) to understand the way to rescue output. 
So I use the command line to rescue output from mysql command line software with switch -e  :

```
             try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("c:/test.txt");
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process proc = rt.exec("mysql.exe -u root -e \"select * from table_name\" database_name");

                StreamGobbler errorGobbler = new StreamGobbler(
                        proc.getErrorStream(), "ERROR");

                StreamGobbler outputGobbler = new StreamGobbler(  proc.getInputStream(), "OUTPUT", fos);

                errorGobbler.start();
                outputGobbler.start();

                int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
                System.out.println("ExitValue: " + exitVal);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
```